# How to start a Xamarin project (emulator error (RedStone 4))

Tags: android, xamarin, hyper-v

I have been trying to install Xamarin for the first time. I have it installed and i have the first dummy project open.  I haven't made any changes to it i am just trying to run it.  **(F5)**

The first thing i am getting is

[image]

I click the learn more which brings me to [Hardware Acceleration for Emulator Performance (Hyper-V & HAXM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin)

Hyper-v is enabled via bios on this machine i know this becomes i also have docker on this machine which runs just fine using hyper-v.  I ran though all the settings in this webpage and it doesnt seam to fix the problem.

I searched the whole page i cant find anything about what windows spring creators update (Redstone 4) is.

If i go though Tools -> Android -> Android device manager.  I get the following screen.

[image]

The here link brings me to the same place as before. (Hyper-V & HAXM)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin)

If i try and run anyway the emulator starts but its not starting with the project.

**SystemInfo**

> Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.

Hyper-v is running Docker has been using it for months.  Yes i disable docker when running this project.

**winver**

> Windows version says Version 1803 (OS build 17134.228) .

**Visual studio version**

> Visual studio 15.8.2

**Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio.**

> Android emulator is at 27.3.9 Android SDK tools is at 26.1.1

What am i doing wrong how do you run an android project using Xamarin.

Comment: Android emulator on Windows runs one of two ways that are not compatible with each other, either Hyper-V or Intel HAXM and as you seen you need to update to the newer version of Windows to use the Hyper-V version. So either update Windows or disable Hyper-V.

Comment: IT just rolled out the windows update I am running the latest Enterprise windows 10.

Comment: That's the latest Enterprise version, not the latest windows version, disable hyper v and install Intel haxm

Comment: I need hyper-v on my machine for docker.   Disabling it is not an option.

Comment: as I said I am running the newest version of Windows 10 are you suggesting installing a beta version or something?    Why would xamarn require that?

Comment: There is a difference between Windows Branching "Servicing Model"... type `winver`, which branch and release are you on?... Microsoft/Xamarin do not "require" that, it is Google related as before HyperV support was added to `emulator` (A Google written app), accelerated x86 emulator was only available via Intel HAXM...

Comment: Well I would assume running Microsoft update I would be on the latest version.  I will run the command first thing Monday but I think its weird that the documentation doent mention it.  it just says set up hyper-v.   And I can use Android developer studio so still sounds like a xamarn thing.

Comment: @SushiHangover Version 1803 (OS build 17134.228)

Answer (score 2):

> How to start Xamarin emulator first time (Redstone 4)

If you want to use `Hyper-V` to accelerate your Android Emulator, you needs [**verifying support for `Hyper-V`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin#accelerating-with-hyper-v):

1. [Verify that your Windows Version is at least 1803](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration-images/win/01-about-windows-w10-sml.png)
2. [Enable windows features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration-images/win/03-hyper-v-settings-w158-sml.png)
3. Install Visual Studio 15.8 or later
4. Install the Android Emulator package 27.2.7 or later
5. Make sure you have enabled the `Virtualization Technology` on your device. You could find it via:

   ```
   Task Manager -> Performance -> Virtualization -> Enable or Disable.
   ```

Comment: As stated i have been though all that Hyper-v is running Docker has been using it for months.    Systeminfo says Hyper-V Requirements: A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.  Windows version says Version 1803 (OS build 17134.228) .  Visual studio 15.8.2. What is the android emulator package?

Comment: @DaImTo, as the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin#accelerating-with-hyper-v) said: navigate to Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager in Visual Studio. Select the Tools tab and ensure that the Android emulator version is at least 27.2.7. Also ensure that the Android SDK Tools version is 26.1.1 or later

Comment: @DaImTo, after that, restart your computer, create a new Android emulator in Android Device Manager and try again.

Comment: Android emulator is at 27.3.9 Android SDK tools is at 26.1.1

Comment: @DaImTo, could you please share your AVD log? You could find it in: `C:\Users\usename\AppData\Roaming\XamarinDeviceManager`